# Ag-grid-Angular version 19 - IE 10 issue

Tags: angular6, internet-explorer-10, ag-grid

My Ag-grid-Angular is not working in IE 10. 
I am using angular version 6.5 and Ag-grid version 19.0.
I am getting error message  **"Expected '/' in vendor.js (168715,55)."**
Can any one suggest any workaround for this.

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: I would recommend testing first the grid in ie10, I believe there are quite a few areas that are not compatible

Comment: I just try to check the sample demo provided on Ag-grid-Angular site. that demo itself contains many errors. You can check in the developer tools. So it is possible that one of the error you are getting on your side. Try to make a test with other browsers to check whether it runs without any issue or not. Try to provide us your code, we will also try to make a test with it. link for that example : https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same issue. I don't know why, but the the compiler in IE 10 can't parse the comments **/*@__PURE__*/** in the generate file vendor.js of the angular. I removed all of the **/*@__PURE__*/** from the mentioned file and the message "Expected '/' ..." in vendor.js dissapeared. However after that there are a lot of error of ag-Grid about missing beans, i'm still working on those.
I dislike the mentioned solution because vendor.js is generated, then those comment should be deleted after every build of the project, but this is as far as I go in this topic by now.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be solved by enabling `optimization: true` in angular.json. but still lot of error of ag-Grid about missing beans. Still working on fixing those